# Why is my validate function not receiving the value of my form element?

Tags: 6, forms

```
function mymodule_email_reviewers_action_form($context) {
  $form = array();
    $form['email_text'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea', 
        '#name' => 'message'
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#name' => '',
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Apply'
    );
  return $form;
}

function mymodule_email_reviewers_action_validate($form, $form_state) {
    $text = $form_state['values']['email_text'];
    dsm($form_state);
    dsm($text);
    dsm($form);
    if ($text == 'Email body' || empty($text)) {
        form_set_error('email_text', t('Please enter a message'));
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what might be wrong here. Neither the `$form` nor `$form_state` contain the text I enter into my textarea.

Comment: reviewing some examples.. may be the mymodule_email_reviewers_action_from function has some mistake? http://www.sysarchitects.com/node/47#comment-205 specifically in $form['keywords'] = array(

Comment: How are you rendering this form. Are you sure if drupal_get_form() is processing your form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [the description for the "#name" attribute](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#name) is reported the following text:

> INTERNAL, except for buttons. All button and submit elements on a form should have the same name, which is set to 'op' by default in Drupal. This does not apply to image buttons. For non-button elements, Drupal sets the name by using 'foo' in $form['foo'] as well as any parents of the element.

You should not set that attribute, which is considered internal.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently setting `#name` is the problem. Taking that out fixed it.